# Require SharePoint Multi-Edit Version Comments in MS Word

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word, vba

My SharePoint library is set up not to force checkout as we want to multi-edit documents. However, after a document is edited, we want to be able to enter a brief summary of why/what was changed. I created a required custom column (Version Comments) which works great. I set the Word document up so that ' Document Properties - Server' show up below the ribbon.  This works great except when I open a document to edit from SharePoint, the previous version comments are still there, which doesn't force the user. Is there a way via VBA to clear that field when the word document opens so the user has to enter comments?

I tried:

ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("NameOfPropery") = "" ' clear 
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("NameOfPropery") = New Comment" ' change

But the property is neither custom nor built in.

Thanks in advance!